# JavaScript: list not displaying

Tags: javascript, html

simple enough I guess but I am a total newbie in this. I tried doing this in PHP but then reconsidered to do it in JS, so I need some help.
The code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
function reply_click(clicked_id)
{
    alert(clicked_id);
    var basketItems=new Array();
    //var i = 0;
    basketItems[1] = clicked_id;

}


</script>
</head>
<body>



    <table height="100%" width="80%" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="10" border="1">
        <tr>
            <td align="center"><input onClick="reply_click(this.name)"  name="shirt" value="shirt" style="width:200px; height:100px;" type="submit"/></td>
            <td align="center"><input onClick="reply_click(this.name)" name="pants" value="pants" style="width:200px; height:100px;" type="submit"/></td>
            <td align="center"><input onClick="reply_click(this.name)"  name="socks" value="socks" style="width:200px; height:100px;" type="submit"/></td>
        <tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center"><input onClick="reply_click(this.name)" name="dress" value="dress" style="width:200px; height:100px;" type="submit"/></td>
            <td align="center"><input onClick="reply_click(this.name)" name="skirt" value="skirt" style="width:200px; height:100px;" type="submit"/></td>
            <td align="center"><input onClick="reply_click(this.name)" name="topbody" value="topbody" style="width:200px; height:100px;" type="submit"/></td>
        <tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center"><input onClick="reply_click(this.name)" name="sheets" value="sheets" style="width:200px; height:100px;" type="submit"/></td>
            <td align="center"><input onClick="reply_click(this.name)" name="pillowcover" value="pillowcover" style="width:200px; height:100px;" type="submit"/></td>
            <td align="center"><input onClick="reply_click(this.name)" name="blanket" value="blanket" style="width:200px; height:100px;" type="submit"/></td>
        <tr>        
    </table>


<div style="width:18%; height:40%;position: absolute; top: 20px; right: 10px; border:2px solid;">
<script type="text/javascript">
var counter=0;
for (counter=0; counter<basketItems.length; counter++)
   document.write(basketItems[counter] + "<br>");
</script>
</div>
<br><br><br>
```

Now what I expected to happen. I click the button, the alert comes out with button name clicked...then it adds that to list. Following it displays that list in the div tag. What happened wrong? it just displays the alert but nothing is shown in the div tag so am assuming something wrong with inserting to array or printing...

Thanks,

UPDATE: This code seems to work on jsfiddle but not on my broswer...any clue what different is there?

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
var basketItems = [];

function reply_click(clicked_id)
{
    alert(clicked_id);
    basketItems.push(clicked_id);

    var html = '';
    for(var i = 0; i < basketItems.length; i++) {
        html += basketItems[i] + '<br/>';   
    }

    document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = html;
}​
</script>
</head>
<body>



    <table height="100%" width="80%" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="10" border="1">
        <tr>
            <td align="center"><input onClick="reply_click(this.name)"  name="shirt" value="shirt" style="width:200px; height:100px;" type="submit"/></td>
            <td align="center"><input onClick="reply_click(this.name)" name="pants" value="pants" style="width:200px; height:100px;" type="submit"/></td>
            <td align="center"><input onClick="reply_click(this.name)"  name="socks" value="socks" style="width:200px; height:100px;" type="submit"/></td>
        <tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center"><input onClick="reply_click(this.name)" name="dress" value="dress" style="width:200px; height:100px;" type="submit"/></td>
            <td align="center"><input onClick="reply_click(this.name)" name="skirt" value="skirt" style="width:200px; height:100px;" type="submit"/></td>
            <td align="center"><input onClick="reply_click(this.name)" name="topbody" value="topbody" style="width:200px; height:100px;" type="submit"/></td>
        <tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center"><input onClick="reply_click(this.name)" name="sheets" value="sheets" style="width:200px; height:100px;" type="submit"/></td>
            <td align="center"><input onClick="reply_click(this.name)" name="pillowcover" value="pillowcover" style="width:200px; height:100px;" type="submit"/></td>
            <td align="center"><input onClick="reply_click(this.name)" name="blanket" value="blanket" style="width:200px; height:100px;" type="submit"/></td>
        <tr>        
    </table>


<div id="list" style="width:18%; height:40%;position: absolute; top: 20px; right: 10px; border:2px solid;">

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and the JS fiddle link is: http://jsfiddle.net/fVQVy/ as posted here as a solution
And thanks all for your patience...greatly appreciated....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/tC8rU/)

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var basketItems=[];

function reply_click(clicked_id) {
   var html = "";
   basketItems.push(clicked_id);
   for (var counter=0; counter<basketItems.length; counter++) 
      html += basketItems[counter] + "<br>";
   // or as posted html = basketItems.join('<br/>');
   document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = html;
}


</script>
</head>
<body>
```

Also make it a button and not submit since that may reload the page

```
    <table height="100%" width="80%" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="10" border="1">
        <tr>
            <td align="center"><input onClick="reply_click(this.name)"  name="shirt" value="shirt" style="width:200px; height:100px;" type="button"/></td>
        <tr>        
    </table>


<div id="result" style="width:18%; height:40%;position: absolute; top: 20px; right: 10px; border:2px solid;">

</div>
<br><br><br>
```

**UPDATE**

Here is how to just add to the result

```
function reply_click(clicked_id) {
   basketItems.push(clicked_id);
   document.getElementById("result").innerHTML+=clicked_id+'<br/>';
}
```

**UPDATE to handle duplicates**

```
var basketItems=[];

function reply_click(clicked_id) {
   if (basketItems.indexOf(clicked_id)==-1) basketItems.push(clicked_id);
   document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = basketItems.join("<br>");
}


// handle duplicates
if(!Array.indexOf) {
  Array.prototype.indexOf = function(obj){
    for(var i=0; i<this.length; i++){
      if (this[i]==obj) return i;
    }
    return -1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that does it...I get the first item as undefined though. What about if I want to maintain the state of the list, so that when I press the next button it adds to list rather than rebuild it? Thanks very much

Comment: I sorted the undefined part...just insert at 0 rather than 1. How about the rest?

Comment: Please see update. Also change submit to button - I need to go to bed. 11pm here.

Comment: you might be sleeping already but just to let you know this is not working...it just doesn't do anything anymore..oh well we have tomorrow

Comment: Aye thanks that's working right now....I really appreciate your effort sir. Good day

Comment: Good day 2u2.  I updated with a duplicate test and a simplified script.

Answer (score 1):

By the time `reply_click` is called, Your script that called `document.write` has already executed.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var basketItems = [];
    function reply_click(clicked_id)  {
      // This does not handle duplicate clicks, leave that up to you
      basketItems.push(clicked_id);
      var out = document.getElementById('output');
      out.innerHTML = basketItems.join('<br/>');
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <table height="100%" width="80%" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="10" border="1">
        <tr>
            <td align="center"><input onClick="reply_click(this.name)"  name="shirt" value="shirt" style="width:200px; height:100px;" type="submit"/></td>
            <td align="center"><input onClick="reply_click(this.name)" name="pants" value="pants" style="width:200px; height:100px;" type="submit"/></td>
            <td align="center"><input onClick="reply_click(this.name)"  name="socks" value="socks" style="width:200px; height:100px;" type="submit"/></td>
        <tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center"><input onClick="reply_click(this.name)" name="dress" value="dress" style="width:200px; height:100px;" type="submit"/></td>
            <td align="center"><input onClick="reply_click(this.name)" name="skirt" value="skirt" style="width:200px; height:100px;" type="submit"/></td>
            <td align="center"><input onClick="reply_click(this.name)" name="topbody" value="topbody" style="width:200px; height:100px;" type="submit"/></td>
        <tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center"><input onClick="reply_click(this.name)" name="sheets" value="sheets" style="width:200px; height:100px;" type="submit"/></td>
            <td align="center"><input onClick="reply_click(this.name)" name="pillowcover" value="pillowcover" style="width:200px; height:100px;" type="submit"/></td>
            <td align="center"><input onClick="reply_click(this.name)" name="blanket" value="blanket" style="width:200px; height:100px;" type="submit"/></td>
        <tr>        
    </table>


<div id='output' style="width:18%; height:40%;position: absolute; top: 20px; right: 10px; border:2px solid;">

</div>
```

Comment: +1 for the push and join. I keep forgetting those when I fix other's scripts

Comment: Any idea why the list is not showing from the above comment since you updated the answer?

Comment: @sys_debug Who is your question directed to?

Comment: Hello Juan, sorry for late answer but it was to you...I was hoping you could help that's all :)

Answer (score 1):

Your `basketItems` array is going to be initialized to an empty array every time your function is called, overwriting the previous entries. Also, you're not adding to it, you're overwriting the second entry (key 1), every time.

Move it outside of the function, into a global scope.

**EDIT:** A fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/3v4W2/1/

Answer (score 1):

You are recreating the array every time you execute reply_click().  Furthermore, the script at the bottom is only executed once during page load.  Please see the following working example -  http://jsfiddle.net/fVQVy/

Comment: This code does exactly what I want in jsfiddle but doesn't work in my copy... :(

Comment: @sys_debug `doesn't work` without an explanation shows very little effort. What kind of error are you getting? Where's the new code?

Comment: Well basically it works there, so I thought it should work anywhere else...just an assumption. I am still looking at it now

Comment: @JuanMendes I am updating my question with the new code which is supposed to work... :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `document.write` code is executed once when the page is loaded, and at that time `baskeItems` is empty.

If you want to dynamically update the page on each click, you should create a function which updates the document, call that function every-time on click

Comment: Actually basketItems in the loop is always empty, the basketItems is a local variable of the reply_click function

Comment: as I said am a total newbie in this case, so can you please help illustrate how that is done...once taught, always will know how to do it and recall upon it :)